# Stackable functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, functional-programming, modularity, control-flow

I am looking for a library agnostic way to "stack" functions. The paradigm's I am used to is "middleware", where something happens within a function errors can be thrown, and a `context` (or `req`) global is used to attach new properties or change existing ones. These ideas are found in libraries like `express`, or `type-graphql`.

I am looking for some agnostic way to chain middleware, not dependent on these type of libraries.

Here's an example of the kinds of functions I have.

I am struggling with some kind of clean way to author functions. The global approach is not complimentary to proper typing using typescript, and isn't very functional.

Where the more functional approach lacks this kind of "chainablity", where I can simply have an array of functions like below.

```
// logs the start of middleware
context.utility.log(debug, ids.onLoad),
// fetches user by email submitted
context.potentialUser.fetchByEmail(SignupOnSubmitArgs),
// throws error if the user is found
context.potentialUser.errorContextPropPresent,
// checks if passowrd and reenterPassword match
context.potentialUser.signupPassword(SignupOnSubmitArgs),
// creates the user
context.user.create(SignupOnSubmitArgs, ''),
// thows error if create failed in some way
context.user.errorContextPropAbsent,
// adds user id to session
context.utility.login,
// redirects user to dashboard
context.utility.redirect(Pages2.dashboardManage)
```

Is there any tools / libraries out there that will allow be to author clear and clean chain-able functions, and glue them together in a stackable way?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#JavaScript

Comment: @RobertHarvey You can't chain async functions in this way without a Proxy. It's a major downside of using this method.

Comment: No, but you could use continuation-passing style with async functions.  See https://2ality.com/2012/06/continuation-passing-style.html

Comment: I am the author of [scriptum](https://github.com/kongware/scriptum) that includes a couple of composition combinators with variadic interfaces, so that you can chain asynchronous computations in a functorial/applicative/monadic way. I use the asynchronous `Task` type in production and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `this` is usually the way for being able to chain methods. I made you an example showing both sync and async functions:

```
class ChainedOperations {
  constructor(private value: number){}

  public add(n: number): this {
    this.value += n;
    return this;
  }

  public subtract(n: number): this {
    this.value -= n;
    return this;
  }

  public async send(): Promise<this> {
    console.log(`Sending ${this.value} somewhere`);
    return this;
  }
}

async function somewhereElse(): Promise<void> {
  const firstChain = await new ChainedOperations(1).add(1).subtract(1).send();
  await firstChain.add(1).subtract(2).send()
}

somewhereElse().catch(e => { throw new Error(e) });
```

For better dealing with async functions you can use pipe pattern where you chain but also wait for the final result and pass it to the next guy:

```
abstract class Pipable {
  public pipe(...functions: Function[]) {
    return (input: any) => functions.reduce((chain, func: any) => chain.then(func.bind(this)), Promise.resolve(input));
  }
}

class AClass extends Pipable {

  constructor(private value: number){
    super();
  }

  public add(n: number): number {
    this.value += n;
    return this.value;
  }

  public subtract(n: number): number {
    this.value -= n;
    return this.value;
  }

  public async send(): Promise<number> {
    console.log(`Sending ${this.value} somewhere`);
    return this.value;
  }
}


async function Something(){
  const myClass = new AClass(2);
  const composition = await myClass.pipe(myClass.add, myClass.subtract, myClass.send)(2);
}

Something();
```

Some people don't like to start from beginning but work their way backwards from the last function. If you want that just replace .reduce with .reduceRight. If you like fancy names, starting from last is called Composing as opposed to piping.

Comment: I can make it more complex if you have a specific case that above is not covering.

Comment: You can't chain async functions in this way without a Proxy. It's a major downside of using this method.

Comment: maybe use pies. see above

Comment: Let me know if you need any more details on this.